# Меню из кнопок для WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Каким образом можно создать подсвечивающееся и выпадающее меню из кнопок в WordPress (везде где смотрел в качестве пунктов меню были ссылки `<a href=""></a>`, а не кнопки - [ссылка на документацию](https://wp-kama.ru/id_140/polzovatelskoe-menyu-v-wp-30-wp_nav_menu.html)

)?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете получить все элементы меню в массив с помощью функции [wp_get_nav_menu_items](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_nav_menu_items) и самостоятельно сформировать удобный для Вас вывод меню

```
$menu_name = 'custom_menu_slug';
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

if( $locations && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) ){

    // получаем элементы меню
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $locations[ $menu_name ] );

    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ){
        $menu_list .= '<button onclick="window.location.href=\'' . $menu_item->url . '\'" onclick="Game()">' . $menu_item->title . '</button>'; 
    }
}
```